# Error in TypeScript code - "Property 'setSelectedFile' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the above error in my TypeScript code. I am attaching the codes of 2 files along with the error message. Please look into it.

This is the "NewPostForm.tsx" file in which error is occuring.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {AlertIcon, Flex, Icon, Alert, Text} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {BiPoll} from "react-icons/bi";
import { BsLink45Deg, BsMic } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { IoDocumentText, IoImageOutline } from 'react-icons/io5';
import {AiFillCloseCircle, AiTwotoneWallet} from "react-icons/ai";
import TabItem from './TabItem';
import TextInputs from "./PostForm/TextInputs"
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ImageUpload from './ImageUpload';
import { User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp, Timestamp, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { firestore, storage } from '../../firebase/clientApp';
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadString } from 'firebase/storage';
import { Post } from '../../atoms/postsAtom';
import useSelectFile from '../../hooks/useSelectFile';

type NewPostFormProps = {
    user: User;
};

const formTabs = [
    {
        title: "Post",
        icon: IoDocumentText,   
    },

    {
        title: "Images & Video",
        icon: IoImageOutline,
    },

    {
        title: "Link",
        icon: BsLink45Deg,
    },

    {
        title: "Poll",
        icon: BiPoll,
    },

    {
        title: "Talk",
        icon: BsMic,
    },
];

export type TabItem = {
    title: string;
    icon: typeof Icon.arguments;
};

const NewPostForm:React.FC<NewPostFormProps> = ({user}) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(formTabs[0].title);
    const [textInputs, setTextInputs] = useState({
        title: "",
        body: "",
    });

    const {selectedFile, setSelectedFile, onSelectFile} = useSelectFile();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);  
    const handleCreatePost = async() => {
        const {communityId} = router.query;
        
        // Create new post object => type Post
        const newPost: Post = {
            communityId: communityId as string,
            creatorId: user?.uid,
            creatorDisplayName: user.email!.split("@")[0],
            title: textInputs.title,
            body: textInputs.body,
            numberOfComments: 0,
            voteStatus: 0,
            createdAt: serverTimestamp() as Timestamp,
            id: ''
        };

        setLoading(true);

        try {
            // Store the post in DB
            const postDocRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "posts"), newPost);

            // Check for selected file
            if(selectedFile)
            {
                // Store in storage => getDownloadURL {return imageURL}
                const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${postDocRef.id}/image`);
                await uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, "data_url");
                const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);

                // Update post doc by adding imageURL
                await updateDoc(postDocRef, {
                    imageURL: downloadURL,
                });
            }
            
        // redirect the user back to the communityPage using the router
        router.back();
    }
        catch(error: any)
        {
            console.log("handleCreatePost error", error.message);
            setError(true);
        }

        setLoading(false);
    };

    const onTextChange = (
        event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
    ) => {
        const {
            target: {name, value},
        } = event;
        setTextInputs((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };
    
    return <div>
        <Flex direction="column" bg="white" borderRadius={4} mt={2}>
            <Flex width="100%">
                {formTabs.map((item) => (
                    <TabItem key={item.title} item={item} selected={item.title === selectedTab}
                    setSelectedTab={setSelectedTab} />
                ))}
            </Flex>
            <Flex p={4}>
                {selectedTab === "Post" && (
                <TextInputs textInputs={textInputs} handleCreatePost={handleCreatePost} 
                onChange={onTextChange} loading={loading} />)}
                {selectedTab === "Images & Video" && (
                    <ImageUpload 
                    selectedFile={selectedFile}
                    onSelectImage={onSelectFile}
                    setSelectedTab={setSelectedTab}
                    setSelectedFile={setSelectedFile} />
                )}
            </Flex>
            {error && (
                <Alert status="error">
                    <AlertIcon />
                    <Text mr={2}>Error Creating the Post</Text>
                </Alert>
            )}
        </Flex>
    </div>
}
export default NewPostForm;
```

Also I am attaching another "useSelectFile.tsx" file for reference.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const useSelectFile = () => {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<string>();

    const onSelectFile = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        console.log("THIS IS HAPPENING", event);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if(event.target.files?.[0])
        {
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }

        reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
            if(readerEvent.target?.result)
            {
                setSelectedFile(readerEvent.target.result as string);
            }
        };
    };

    return 
    {
        selectedFile
        setSelectedFile
        onSelectFile
    };
};

export default useSelectFile;
```

Also I am attaching the screenshot of error message.
[image]

Comment: The error persists for all 3 properties i.e. selectedFile, setSelectedFile, onSelectFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have return nothing from your hook file and the return object you are expecting is wrong

Try this

```
 return {
        selectedFile,
        setSelectedFile,
        onSelectFile,
    };
```

a working sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lumiere-xuqonh?file=/hooks/useSelectFile.tsx)

Comment: I already tried using commas but it is not working. If I put commas then in the return the following error came up "Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.ts(2695)".

Comment: i have added a sandbox link, please check that

Answer (score 2):

You have newline after return, so you are not returning anything from your useSelectFile hook. Remove the line break in return statement:)